# Python ошибка в синтаксисе

Tags: python, python-3.x, синтаксис

не могу разобраться, где в коде ошибка

```
import random
print("для выхода напишите.")

while True
a = input("ведите вопрос:")
number = random.randint(1,5)
if(a = .)
    break
if(number = 1)
    print("да")
if(number = 2)
    print("нет")
if(number = 3)
    print("и да и нет")
if(number = 4)
    print("скорее да чем нет")
if(number = 5)
    print("скорее нет чем да")
```

Comment: Да в каждой второй строчке ошибка, а в некоторых даже по две. Нужно брать учебник и читать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Много ошибок:

```
while True
```

отсутствует двоеточие (`:`) в конце. Правильно:

```
while True:
```

---

```
a = input("ведите вопрос:")
```

Это и последующие команды должны быть в цикле `while True:`, значит, должны быть отступы. Правильно:

```
    a = input("ведите вопрос:")
```

---

```
if(a = .)
```

Три ошибки в этой строке, и во всех похожих первые 2 из них:

- отсутствует двоеточие (`:`) в конце,
- оператор сравнения не `=`, а `==`,
- точка (`.`) должна быть в кавычках, потому что это не число, а символ, так: `"."`,
- скобки не нужны (но могут быть — это не является ошибкой).

Правильно:

```
if a == ".":
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
print("для выхода напишите.")

while True:
    a = input("ведите вопрос:")
    number = random.randint(1,5)

    if a == 'quit':
        break
    elif number == 1:
        print("да")
    elif number == 2:
        print("нет")
    elif number == 3:
        print("и да и нет")
    elif number == 4:
        print("скорее да чем нет")
    elif number == 5:
        print("скорее нет чем да")
```